# Make surface in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have point cloud in 3D. I want make surface in three.js. I added point in Geometry with Vector3.

```
for(var key in dt)
{
var hole = dt[key];
var pX = hole['x'] - planeMinX;
var pY = hole['y'] - planeMinY;
var pZ = hole['z'];
gPlane.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ));
}
```

How compute faces? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

A point cloud is just that. If you dont have the face connectivity information there is no way to compute it. Well there is but it is an algorithmic problem. If your point cloud is very dense then in order to visualize your data you probably dont have to compute the faces. You can visualize the points as they are. You can use the particle system in three.js to get an idea of your data. Take a look at the example webgl_buffergeometry_particles.html

Comment: Oh... Thank you, but I need to surface reconstruction. May be I will do surface reconstruction in C++ (it has the appropriate libraries) and send data to browser. Pity that there is no ready solutions.

Comment: pcl library in C++ will be better